# How to upload a file in Umbraco 8 and set it's value to file upload datatype

Tags: umbraco, umbraco8

[Image for uploaded file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWP9K.png)Is there a simple way to upload file to a media folder in Umbraco 8 at controller level, and setting it as a value for a file upload datatype. This is the code I am have used for version 7 and it seemed to work fine:

```
        if (model.FileUpload != null)
        {
            IMediaService mediaService = Services.MediaService;
            var media = mediaService.CreateMedia(model.FileUpload.FileName, 1834, "File");
            media.SetValue("umbracoFile", model.FileUpload.InputStream);
            mediaService.Save(media);
            content.SetValue("entry", $"media/{media.Key}");

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried it in v8? If so, and it didn't work, are you getting any error messages? Only thing off the top of my head is that maybe your parent ID now needs to be a UDI.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding Jannik, there is no error message and everything submits seamlessly but in the backoffice media folder, the file is either null or has system.inputstrem as path

Comment: I have edited my question to add screenshot of the current uploaded file

Comment: @SabRa Is this helpful? `https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/management/services/mediaservice/#creating-a-new-media-from-an-uploaded-file`